# How to print generator object yielded value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

I'm trying to make a class I created into an infinite series generator.

The class is basically like this (I omitted the other methods as it is large):

```
class Step(object):
    ''' A Step taken through a field. '''
    def __init__(self, step_id, offset, danger,
        danger_limit=None, is_encounter = None, input=None):
        self.step_id = step_id
        self.offset = offset
        self.danger = danger
        self.is_encounter = is_encounter
        self.rnd = self.get_rnd(self.step_id, self.offset)
        self.danger_limit = self.get_danger_limit(self.rnd)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}'.format(
            self.step_id, self.offset, self.danger,
            self.rnd, self.danger_limit, self.is_encounter, self.input)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def advance_step(self, danger_inc=113):
        ''' To help with generator functions. '''
        # Advances the current step, so make a current step object.
        old_Step = Step(step_id=self.step_id, offset=self.offset, danger=self.danger)

        step_id = Step.get_step_id(old_Step.step_id)
        offset = Step.get_offset(step_id, old_Step.offset)
        danger = Step.get_danger(danger_inc, old_Step.danger, old_Step.danger_limit)
        new_step = Step(step_id = step_id, offset = offset, danger = danger)
        new_step.is_encounter = Step.is_encounter(new_step.danger,
            new_step.danger_limit)
        return new_step

    def next(self):
        ''' Yields next step in sequence. '''
        while True:
            yield self.advance_step()
```

I want to print a sequence of step objects. So I tried this:

```
def main():
    step = Step(step_id=250, offset=13, danger=0)
    print step.next()
    # Generate next 4 steps in sequence.
    for i in xrange(4):
        print step.next()
```

However, I get this output:

```
<generator object next at 0x104364cd0>
<generator object next at 0x104364cd0>
<generator object next at 0x104364cd0>
<generator object next at 0x104364cd0>
<generator object next at 0x104364cd0>
```

Expected output should look like a sequence of Step objects:

```
0   250 13  2048    0   74  19200   False   None
1   252 13  2048    2048    216 55552   False   None
2   254 13  2048    4096    163 41984   False   None
3   0   26  2048    6144    151 38912   False   None
4   2   26  2048    8192    212 54528   False   None
```

I get the expected output if I do the following:

```
step2 = step.advance_step()
step3 = step2.advance_step()
step4 = step3.advance_step()
print step,'\n', step2,'\n', step3,'\n', step4
```

How can I print the yielded step objects and not get the generator object back?

I suppose I'm doing something very wrong, but I cannot see what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `next()` method must return **one** value in the sequence the iterable represents. You returned a generator for each step.

Simply return the next value, there is no need to use a loop here:

```
def next(self):
    ''' Yields next step in sequence. '''
    return self.advance_step()
```

You could just rename `advance_step()` to `next()` of course.

From the [`iterator.next()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next):

> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the `StopIteration` exception.